# Nextjs 13.4 error.tsx, the reset() not working (for fetch)

Tags: reactjs, reload, reset, next.js13

I am using the App router, error.tsx page.
I am using a server component that have fetch data from "json-server" so when the server is down the error.tsx appears with a try again button. after running the server, I click on the try again button which calls the reset() method but nothing reloads (the fetch should occur normally)

the component is called in a server component

```
import { Ticket } from "@/models/ticket";
import { log } from "console";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import TicketCard from "./ticketCard";

const getTickets = async () => {
  //Imitate Delay
  // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/tickets", {
   next: { revalidate: 0 /*Seconds - 0 removes cahcing*/ },
  });
  return response.json();
};

export default async function TicketList() {
  const tickets: Ticket[] = await getTickets();

  return (
    <section className="flex flex-col">
      {tickets.map((ticket: any) => <TicketCard ticket={ticket} key={ticket.id} />).reverse()}
      {tickets.length === 0 && (
        <p className="text-center text-2xl font-bold">No Tickets Yet!</p>
      )}
    </section>
  );
}
```

error.tsx

```
"use client"; // Error components must be Client Components

import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Error({
  error,
  reset,
}: {
  error: Error & { digest?: string };
  reset: () => void;
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Log the error to an error reporting service
    //
    console.error(error);
  }, [error]);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center m-auto pt-16 ">
      <h2>Something went wrong!</h2>
      <p className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-3">
        Error Message :: {error.message}
      </p>
      <div className="flex gap-4">
        <button
          className="rounded-md py-2 px-4 mt-6 bg-yellow-500 text-white"
          onClick={
            // Attempt to recover by trying to re-render the segment
            () => reset()
          }
        >
          Try again
        </button>
        <Link
          href="/"
          className="rounded-md py-2 px-4 mt-6 bg-green-600 text-white"
        >
          Go Home
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using the App router, error.tsx page.
I am using a server component that have fetch data from "json-server" so when the server is down the error.tsx appears with a try again button. after running the server, I click on the try again button which calls the reset() method but nothing reloads (the fetch should occur normally)

Comment: I have run into the same problem. I have been following the Learn Nextjs tutorial. The tutorial was pretty good but they never gave an example on how to handle data fetch errors. I also tried the reset function but with no success. It does nothing

Answer (score 2):

I could solve it with below method.

Before:

```js
onClick={
  // Attempt to recover by trying to re-render the segment
  () => reset()
}
```

After:

```js
onClick={
  // Attempt to recover by trying to re-render the segment
  router.refresh() // used useRouter() hook
  startTransition(reset)
}
```

I came up with this idea with below assumptions

- `reset()` uses previous error result again, rather than re-render server components and use that result to retry.
- refreshing page does re-render server components.
- Due to React's batching, we need to use `startTransition()`

  - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/45829#discussioncomment-4954973
  - I tested it with sequentially clicking two buttons

    - (first one performs refresh and second one performs reset) => Worked
  - So I used `startTransition()` to `reset` function.